# Making GWT custom widget

Tags: web-applications, gwt, widget

i want to make a GWT widget that looks like google+'s circle.

I checked on google's GWT website but they say that I have to look at the GWT source code (which is quite hard to understand for me)

I wonder if there exist any tutorial on making a custom GWT widget by using java?

Comment: Well, if you want circles functionality, you will need events like drag handler and drop handler (which aren't native to gwt <2.4). If you need some animation too, you will have to look at gwt canvas (wont work on IE<8 and maybe not even 8). Not saying you cant do it though.

Comment: I would like to do something similar as well.  It is definitely possible, but your going to have to do some native javascript.  Look at http://gwt-cloudtask.appspot.com for opensource example of drag and drop with GWT.  The source code is available on google code, just do a search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this :

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets.html